# Highslide: How do you use highslide javascript library to show HTML from a different page?

Tags: highslide

Is it at all possible to use the highslide library to show HTML from a different page on the site?

I'd like to do something like this...

```
hs.htmlExpand("../aDifferentPage.aspx?123")
```

I'm assuming its not possible because all of the [online API](http://www.highslide.com/ref/hs.htmlExpand) documentation only references the ability to load parts of the page from where the call is made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this "bare bones" example: http://highslide.com/examples/iframe.html

You can put any URL in the "a href" portion, like http://www.example.com. You'd want to take it further and specify things like height and width, of course.

Comment: Thanks. I can put the <a href.. on the page then use the script to call this link.